# textView.setText not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, textview

I have a TextView in a fragment called "frontpage". In my MainActivity (also called frontpage, and the fragment is also there), I want to change the text of my textview. Here is my code in the Mainactivity:

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

```
public PlaceholderFragment() {


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frontpage, container, false);
    return rootView;

}
public void setText(String text){
    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.NameView);
    textView.setText("HI!");
}
```

}

And here is my code in the xml layout for the textview:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/NameView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

No errors are being shown, but when running the app, the textview stays empty. Why is that?

Comment: override `onViewCreated` and call the method

Comment: Where are you calling your setText method?

Comment: Alright, I have realized I haven't called it anywhere, so the question is, WHERE should I call it? (sorry for these basic questions, I'm a beginner and this is my first app, so I am programming and learning on the side.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you never called your setText(String) function! JVM will follow what you tell it to and you never asked it to go and execute seText(String) function :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code above return rootView.

```
setText("Hi");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frontpage, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
    textView.setText("Hi");
    return rootView;

}
```